# Nuxt getting Error: Can't resolve '@tailwindcss/base'

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Building a project using NUXT and Tailwind 2.  I get the error

> Error: Can't resolve '@tailwindcss/base'

My package.json file is:

```json
{
  "name": "vite-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^3.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
    "nuxt-purgecss": "^1.0.0",
    "nuxt-vite": "0.0.36",
    "postcss": "^8.1.9",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.5",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

My nuxt.config.js file has

```js
build: {
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      'postcss-import': {},
      tailwindcss: path.resolve(__dirname, './tailwind.config.js'),
      'postcss-nested': {}
    }
  },
  preset: {
    stage: 1 // see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#future-css-featuress
  }
}
```

And then my tailwind.css is

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Answer (score 6):

Prefix your path with tilde `~`

```css
@import "~tailwindcss/base";
@import "~tailwindcss/components";
@import "~tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Also there is a special directive called **tailwind**. So you may try

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I updated how I was calling tailwind and it worked.